# Do 'ration' and 'station' rhyme in any English accents?

Tags: accent, rhymes

In Kipling's *Bridge Guard in the Karoo*, there is a verse

> We stumble on refuse of rations,
>
> The beef and the biscuit-tins;
>
> We take our appointed stations,
>
> And the endless night begins.

'Ration' and 'station' sounds to me like an eye-rhyme, as the 'a' in ration is short but the 'a' in station is long. Are there accents where those two words have the same 'a' sound?

Comment: When you say "English accent", could you please be a little more specific, England is infamous for having a hundreds of local or regional accents. For example, Estuary English and cockney English sound nothing like the English accent that you hear Hue Grant speaking with in most of his movies, and these sound nothing like a west Midland's accent.

Comment: @AaarghZombies yes, but the question is asking whether *any* of these accents rhyme the two words, not about what a particular accent does.

Comment: @Especially Lime, there are approximately 56 different English accents in England alone, and over 100 more when you count English the US\Canada\Australia\New Zealand and England's former colonies in the Caribbean, India, Africa and Asia. Many of these rhyme those two words. If I know a little more about what the OP has in mind I can provide them with a much better answer.

Comment: @AaarghZombies The questioner is asking about a Rudyard Kipling poem. If the plethora of English accents is actually the thing limiting your ability to improve upon the three answers which existed when you made your original comment, I would recommend concentrating on those which Kipling would have been familiar with. (i.e. which accent might he have been speaking if he thought the two words rhymed.)

Comment: @R.M, Kipling was born and raised in India, but spent considerable portions of his life in South Africa, Southern England and South Western England. He is known to have associated with people from all over the former British Empire. It would help if we knew the perspective of the OP, hence my original question as to whether they were limiting this to "Queen's English", or if they wanted to include local or regional accents.

Comment: I actually thought this was just an 'imperfect rhyme'  - there's no requisite in poetry per-se for it to actually rhyme at all.  Not all poems rhyme,  many rhymes aren't poems.

Comment: For what it's worth, I pronounce the verb form as ray-shun and the noun as raah-shun. I have a raised in Miami, FL accent.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

***[Ration](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ration)*** pronunciation changed over time as suggested by the following extract from Etymonline. Kipling probably  used the older more common pronunciation used in England at his time:

> The military pronunciation (rhymes with fashion) took over in English from the preferred civilian pronunciation (rhymes with nation) during World War I. That war also gave the word a specific sense of "officially limited allowance for civilians in times of war or dearth" (by 1917).

The following comment from [quora.com](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Singaporeans-pronounce-ration-as-ray-shun-instead-of-how-it-is-actually-supposed-to-be-pronounced) provides some  more interesting points:

> Both pronunciations are acceptable and have been heard in cultivated speech since the word entered English in the mid-19th century. OED 1 (1904 ed.) gave priority to RAY-shin, but by the 1930s RASH-in was the prevailing pronunciation in England. American dictionaries gave priority to RAY-shin until the 1940s, but since then RASH-in has been listed first (as it is in the four leading current American dictionaries).

Comment: Lewis Carroll rhymed _rations_ with _quotations_ in _The Hunting of the Snark_.

Comment: @ColinFine — I wouldn't put it past good ol’ Lewis to pronounce it *quo-tash-uns* to rhyme with *rash-uns*.

Comment: @TinfoilHat: He'd do that sort of thing on occasion, but only when he was making a point of the wordplay. He wouldn't drop it in there.

Comment: @TinfoilHat, @ ColinFine: off-topic, but hard to resist quoting my favourite rhyme from Carroll: “The hues of life are dull and gray, // The sweets of life insipid, // When thou, my charmer, art away— // Old brick, or rather, let me say, // Old parallelepiped!”  (from [*Phantasmagoria*](https://americanliterature.com/author/lewis-carroll/poem/phantasmagoria))

Comment: I wonder if it's from French, like *materiel*. «Ration» is pronounced /ʁasjɔ̃ / in French, which some dialects might render as [ʁaʃjõ].

Answer (score 11):

As [Merriam-Webster notes,](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ration) "ration" has two alternate pronunciations, one of which rhymes with "station." [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ration) lists the pronunciations in IPA as /'ræʃ.ən/ and /ˈreɪ.ʃən/, the latter of which rhymes with "station" (/'steɪ.ʃən/).

Comment: And the one that rhymes with _station_ is the most common in the US, both as a noun and a verb. The one that rhymes with _passion_ is less common. Of course, the concept and therefore the word are rare because old-fashioned.

Comment: @JohnLawler Do you mean most common in the UK? I'm in the US and have only heard the version rhyming with *passion.*

Comment: Really? I've heard it, of course, since I'm 81, but not often. It sounds vaguely British (the UK had rationing long after the US) and vaguely WWIIish. But that's just me; I haven't conducted any surveys.

Comment: @JohnLawler Huh. I'm in the Northeast US, in my 20s; I've never come across this pronunciation and didn't know about it until I looked it up. I've always heard it as rhyming with "passion." Rudyard Kipling (the author in question) was British, so clearly it isn't just in AmE.

Comment: @JohnLawler I'm in Ontario, and I've only ever heard it rhyming with "passion" as well.

Comment: @JohnLawler: I think the pronunciation must be regional. I live in the Northeast, and while I've heard the pronunciation rhyming with *nation*, it usually rhymes with passion.

Comment: @PeterShor If you’ll gird up your rhyme just a word at a time, it’s a rational bet that a ration you’ll get.

Comment: I grew up in USA (California) hearing it both ways, and to this day I pronounce it both ways, depending, I guess, on how it sounds to my mind in a given sentence.  But much more often rhyming with "station".

Answer (score 10):

As the other answers have noted, *ration* is sometimes pronounced similarly to station, nation, and the like. This is a pronunciation that's noted in some dictionaries.

---

**Edit**:

So, I've looked through some of Kipling's other works and found the following line in *[The Masque of Plenty](https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/poem/poems_masque.htm) (13):*

> God bless the Squire
> And all his rich **relations**
> Who teach us poor people
> We eat our proper **rations** --
> We eat our proper **rations**,
> In spite of **inundations**,
> Malarial **exhalations**,
> And casual **starvations**,
> We have, we have, they say we have --
> We have our proper **rations**!

It's even clearer here that Kipling felt that 'rations' rhymed with 'starvations,' 'exhalations,' 'inundations,' and 'relations.' He likely had a non-standard pronunciation of the word.

Bizarrely, though, we see this line in *[The New Knighthood](https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/poem/poems_knighthood.htm)*:

> "Who fastens his belt?
> "I," said **Short-Rations,**
> " I know all the **fashions**
> "Of tightening a belt!"

So it seems that Kipling either stretched the pronunciation to fit the rhyme or that he pronounced it both ways- this isn't that uncommon; lots of people use both pronunciations when referring to *caramel* or *Nevada*, so why not *rations?*

---

Now, as for your question about whether any accent pronounces 'stations' and 'rations' with the same ending, one specific accent in which I've noticed this happen a lot is **the Indian accent.** In the Indian accent, both words are pronounced with a completely different sound- not /eɪ/ or /æ/, but an /eː/ sound. (The other two sounds appear in very few Indian languages)

I can't find any citations for this, but I've consistently observed Indians (both from the North, South, and surrounding subcontinent) pronouncing 'ration' as /ˈreːʃən/. (Some) North Indians also do the same with *fashion*, and *passion*, and I've heard it in inflected/derived forms of these words (/ˈfeːʃnəbəl/ , ˈ/ˈpeːʃənətliː/ , /ˈreːʃənd/).

Also, a [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-Singaporeans-pronounce-ration-as-ray-shun-instead-of-how-it-is-actually-supposed-to-be-pronounced) thread suggests that Singaporeans do this too. There's a fair amount of cultural exchange between Singapore and India, so that could be a possible connection. Kipling also spent a small part of his life in India.

While the Indian accent doesn't fall in the conventional classification of 'native' English (the Western trilogy of American, British, and  Antipodean), this is one accent that pronounces the two as rhymes.

---

Also, see [this](https://www.getyarn.io/yarn-clip/beece9f7-10a7-4a89-8b42-e84e3fce4d07) clip from *Gilligan's Island,* which was supposedly famous for this pronunciation- perhaps *that's* where Kipling picked it up ;)

Comment: I think the OP was referring to native, rather than foreign, accents.  I don't think any native speaker anywhere pronounces ration like /ˈreːʃən/.

Comment: @HollisWilliams - You may be right about the OP's intention; I interpreted it as referring to _any_ accent. But you're right that /ˈreːʃən/ is a nonstandard, nonnative pronunciation.

Comment: Though often overlooked when counting native English accents, Indian English is one of the major native English-language families since it does have first-language speakers and is an official language of India with mandatory use in parts of government. Wikipedia cites the Indian census for ~250 million speakers, with "a few hundred thousand" first-language speakers. You're not wrong at all to count Indian English accents as native rather than foreign, no more than for e.g. Scottish English.

Comment: I checked Wikipedia and Indian English (IE) is classed as a group of English dialects spoken in the Republic of India, whereas Scottish and American English are classed as sets of *varieties* of the English language, which is a different thing as far as I can tell.

Comment: That's a very interesting find in *The New Nighthood*

Answer (score 4):

Just one data point: The American dog food Ken-L-Ration pronounces it to rhyme with station in their ads.

(Or at least, that's how I remember it, and how I've always pronounced the brand name. Memory could be wrong, if course. But I *have* heard both in the Northeastern US. Then again, the northeast alone has accents/dialects running from Proper Bostonian to State Of Mainer to Brooklynese, so vowels don't just shift here, they rotate and multiply.)

Comment: How does this answer the question?  Generation and adoration also rhyme with station, but what about ration?

Comment: @livresque They just said that *ration* rhymes with *station* in those ads.

Comment: (In case it isn't obvious, the name is derived from "kennel ration.")

Comment: I haven't otherwise heard that in AmE. Could that example be influenced by *generation*, *adulation*, etc.?

Comment: Seems unlikely, unless they had a rhyming advertising jingle. I have heard both here in the Northeast, to the point where I am honestly not sure which I would say spontaneously without this question cueing me.

Comment: The film "Demolition Man" has a scene where a "Ken-L-Ration" minitune (advert) is played on a car radio and that definitely rhymes with "passion"; since we all know "Demolition Man" is a serious academic study (virtually a documentary) I think that says it all...

Comment: Hm. Not how I remember it.

Answer (score 1):

Are there accents in which they *don't* rhyme?

ˈra-shən
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ration

ˈstā-shən

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/station

If you're operating under the idea that a "rhyme" requires all vowel sounds to match, then I am baffled as to where this idea came from. Are you bothered by the fact that only the terminal vowels in "biscuit-tins" and "begins" match (although the e in "begins" can be reduced to match the ui in "biscuit")?

> rhyme
> 1 of 2
> noun
> ˈrīm
> variants or less commonly rime
> Synonyms of rhyme
> 1
> a
> (1)
> : rhyming verse
> (2)
> : POETRY
> b
> : a composition in verse that rhymes
> 2
> a
> : correspondence in terminal sounds of units of composition or utterance (such as two or more words or lines of verse)
> b
> : one of two or more words thus corresponding in sound
> c
> : correspondence of other than terminal word sounds: such as
> (1)
> : ALLITERATION
> (2)
> : INTERNAL RHYME

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rhyme

Comment: A common convention in English rhyme is that the vowels and consonants should match from the stressed vowel on. Since “ration” and “station” are stressed on the first syllable, this and not only the second syllable has to match for them to rhyme according to that rhyme system. “begins” is stressed on the second syllable and “biscuit-tins” has a secondary stress on the last syllable, which can be counted as stress for the sake of rhyme